# Zombie process in linux

Tags: linux

I am learning about fork system call where it mentions about zombie process . when does it happen when using fork() system call
Can anyone explain in simple sentence because  I am a beginner .

Comment: Wikipage on [zombie process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process) is explaining that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If fork() returns a negative value, the creation of a child process was unsuccessful.

fork() returns a zero to the newly created child process.

fork() returns a positive value, the process ID of the child process, to the parent.

*Zombie process is a process state when the child dies before the parent process. 
In this case the structural information of the process is still in the process table

If you want more clarification inform me

Comment: What is an process table ? What do you mean by structural information?

Comment: Process table maens, simply think like all the processes which are active in the system stored in a table with their PID(Process ID).  Structural information means ,just the PID of a particular process and tags like if it is active or not in the system at given time

Comment: Is there a way to overcome zombie process?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about them. They do not occupy any resources, they will disappear either when their parent calls wait() on when the parent itself dies.